# How to manage 100+ websites hosting and deployment

Tags: hosting, deployment, website

Currently we have a VPS that hosts over 100 websites using PHP-FPM and NGINX.

They are a mix of Symfony, CakePHP and plain PHP.
We also use Git to deploy.

Pros

- All in one place
- Updates done at once

Cons

- Server upgrades take all sites down
- Broken updates take all sites down

Now we are looking to include HTTPS for the sites, and as we are supporting Windows XP, will need an additional IP per site.

This has got me thinking that maybe we should have one VPS per site, and that would get us the IP per site, but also decrease the chance of all sites going offline at once.
The downside would this would be a pain to manage by hand.

Is this the right path to go down and what we do to improve our website deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now we are looking to include HTTPS for the sites, and as we are supporting Windows XP, will need an additional IP per site.

No you don't. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Netscape have all supported Subject Alternative Names SSL extension since 2003. Internet Explorer has actually supported them since Windows 98.

The Subject Alternative Name extension allows multiple, different domain names in a single certificate. Such a SAN or UCC certificate, while exactly not cheap, may be more economical than 100 individual certificates and is definitely cheaper than getting a 99 additional servers up and running.

Comment: Impressive. SAN certificate isn't something I'd considered.

Comment: @DanielP It's a good choice if all the sites are related, or at least owned by the same entity. If you're hosting sites on behalf of other entities, it's not really going to work very well, if you can get the certificate at all! Though you really shouldn't be supporting XP anymore.

Comment: All the website are own by the same entity, so it's possible.  We are operating consumer websites, so Window XP needs to be supported.